# Java Result: -1073740940 - I get this when I run the code, now all my code won't run

Tags: java, jdbc

So I have this code.. I ran it and gave the following message.

```
run:
Java Result: -1073740940
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 21 seconds)
```

After that.. Even previous projects that were all working properly won't even run. they all give me the same result. I have looked all over for a solution, but none of the people on the forums even get the problem whenever anyone asks it.

Here is the code.. Long, I know.. But I hope it helps. The error began when I added the SQL connections to the sign up button and wrote the saveName function.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.lang.Exception.*;

public class SmartStock extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;

public void saveName(String FirstName,String LastName,String SurName, String Password) throws SQLException{

    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver//:localhost:1433/USERS";
    String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    String userName = ""; 
    String password = "";


    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO USER_PERSONAL_DETAILS(forename, lastname, surname, password) VALUES ('','"+txtFName.getText()+ "','" +txtLName.getText()+"','"+txtSName.getText()+"','"+nwpassword.getText()+"'");

    }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SmartStock.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SmartStock.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}

   //In here is the JFrame for the code.. Long so I trimmed it off.

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


    if(e.getSource()==btnSignup){         
        String fname = txtFName.getText();
        String lname=txtLName.getText();
        String sname=txtSName.getText();
        String pword=nwpassword.getText();

        try{
            saveName(fname,lname,sname,pword);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SmartStock.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        new SignUp();
        dispose();
   }
    else if(e.getSource()==btnExit){
        System.exit(0);
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title should me more descriptive.

Comment: Your question seems to be about JDBC. Please trim down your code and remove everything that is not related tot the problem. Swing and AWT have nothing to do with database access.

Comment: Done..Edited the title too.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Any exception? What's the stack trace?

Comment: No exceptions.. No errors.. That is all I am getting.

Comment: -1073740940 is 0xc0000374 in hex, and a quick Google for that error code indicates heap corruption.  That suggests to me either (a) Java has become corrupted and needs reinstallation, or (b) you're having issues with SQL Server and integrated security (sqljdbc_auth.dll), although your JDBC connection URL above doesn't mention integrated security.  Are you using Windows authentication or SQL Server authentication to connect to SQL Server?  Also, are you deliberately using a blank username/password or is that just how you've chosen to anonymise them here?